# Deserialized object type casting at runtime

Tags: c#, casting, windows-phone-8

Say I have this class hierarchy:

```
public abstract class Base {};
public class Child1 : Base {};
public class Child2 : Base {};
```

At some point I persist one of inherited classes in `IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings` and then get it back as `object`. How can I find out whether it is `Child1` or `Child2` and type cast it to right type at runtime?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you not just use is ?

```
if(myobject is Child1)
    var child1 = (Child1)myobject;
else if (myobject is Child2)
    ....
```

Comment: Thanks, this works for my case since I only have two invariants. But, hypothetically, what if I did not know the type of object at all? Is there any more elegant solution that does not involve `if-else` enumeration?

Comment: @Anton If you don't know the type at all, why would you want to cast it? You need to cast it only to call a specific property or method, which means that you know the underlying type.

Comment: @KooKiz yeah, I've formulated an example situation poorly. The question still holds, however. In my opinion `if-else` is not too elegant.

Comment: @Anton If you need to call a method defined in `Base`, then you just need to cast your object to `Base`, no matter if it's a child type. If you need to call a method of `Child1` or `Child2`, you're going to write a specific portion of code to call this method. So the if/else doesn't change much. The only case I see where it could be troublesome is if you have a method with an overload for both `Child1` and `Child2`: `void Method(Child1 obj)` and `void Method(Child2 obj)`. The usual workaround for this case is to use the `dynamic` keyword, which unfortunately doesn't exist on Windows Phone.

Comment: @KooKiz Indeed, you are right. My situation is such that I need to call a method that is defined in `Base` and redefined on children. After some research now I see that `virtual/override` will solve my problem without need to guess exact subtype.

Comment: I'd suggest casting to a common interface, and doing away with the inheritance chain altogether :)

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way would be casting it using `as` keyword and checking the result:

```
Base child;
child = mysteryObject as Child1;
if(child == null)
{
    // mysteryObject is Child2
    child = mysteryObject as Child2;
}
else
{
    // mysteryObject is Child1
}
```

You could also use `is` keyword instead.